# Does google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip includes com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders and com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

api-java-client-1.17.0-rc into my project but getting following error:

```
The import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders cannot be resolved
The import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser cannot be resolved
```

If I include 1.10.3, then I don't get the error anymore...
Please advice what are the thing I'll miss using 1.10.3 instead of 1.17. And why I'm getting those errors?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the documentation for [JsonHttpParser](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.12.0-beta/com/google/api/client/http/json/package-summary.html) as at 1.12 it was scheduled to be removed in 1.13. It suggests you use [JsonObjectParser](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser.html) instead.

GoogleHeaders was [removed](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=660) in 1.13.2. Suggestion is to use HttpHeaders instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
I solved it by placing those .jar files in libs directory:
google drive url (for .jar files) :

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xsVmEp_l0LhzT0Fbkfd5whfrfHRVK1OB?usp=sharing

then sync your project.